# Can't access Sql Server from remote PC

Tags: java, sql-server, servlets

I am working on Screenshare using **Red5**. I have a servlet that gets and displays clients sharing screen from Sql Server using `ResultSet`. My Pc acts as the **Sql server** and am able to display the table using servlet in my red5 server.

But the servlet in red5 server in another PC which is connected to my PC(which has the sql server) through lan cannot access the database and the servlet screen is blank

I get

> Cannot open database requested by the login.

I changed the IP to my PC in the servlet, but that caused the WebStart application to stop working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check the username and password.weather it is correct or no

Comment: it's correct..the servlet in my red5 server can access it